# How to perform WHERE in with multiple columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I wants to do something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM product p
                    JOIN product_version pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
                    where (p.code, pv.product_version) in (("FF6",1), ("FF12", 1));
```

But this is giving error at **in** clause.
Can someone provide the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing any information about the actual error neither about column types.

But, by the way, it really looks like that those double quotes are wrong because in Postgres strings are quoted using simple quotes (`'`), not double (`"`).

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
JOIN product_version pv ON (p.id = pv.product_id)
where
    (p.code, pv.product_version) in (('FF6',1), ('FF12', 1))
;
```

Despite that, your query looks syntactically "correct" unless some kind of type mismatching we cannot foresee without more information.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is because of the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't go with `IN`, depending on your goal you need to do something like:

```sql
where (p.code = "FF6" and pv.product_version = 1) or
(p.code = "FF12" and pv.product_version = 1)
```

or, if the logic above was not what you meant, maybe:

```sql
where p.code IN ("FF6", "FF12} AND pv.product_version IN (1)
```

or

```sql
where p.code IN ("FF6", "FF12} OR pv.product_version IN (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you

```
SELECT * FROM product p
                    JOIN product_version pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
                    where p.code in("FF6","FF12") and pv.product_version = 1
```